# Solidity compiler throwing [ ':1:1: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition.\n

Tags: solidity

**Trying to compile below solidity code:**

**Deploy.js**

```
let path = require('path');
```

let fs = require('fs');
let solc = require('solc');

let voterPath = path.resolve(__dirname,'Voter.sol');
let srcCodeObj =  fs.readFileSync(voterPath, 'UTF-8');

let voterInput = {
language:'Solidity',
sources:{
'Voter.sol':{
content:srcCodeObj,
},
},
settings:{
outputSelection:{
'*':{
'*':["abi", "evm.bytecode"],
},
},
},
};

try {
console.log("Compiling");
let output = solc.compile(JSON.stringify(voterInput));
console.log(output);
console.log("Compiled");
} catch(Ex) {
console.log("Exception occured");
console.log(Ex);
}

**Voter.sol**

```
pragma solidity >0.4.2;
```

contract Voter {

```
struct OptionPos {
    uint pos;
    bool exists;
}

/*constructor(string memory passedName) public {
}*/

// Fields
uint[] public votes;
string[] public options;
mapping(address=>bool) hasVoted;
mapping(string=>OptionPos) posOfOption;
bool votingStarted;

function addOption(string memory option) public {
    require(!votingStarted);
    options.push(option);
}

function startVoting() public{
    require(!votingStarted);
    //votes.length = options.length;
    
    for (uint cnt = 0; cnt < options.length; cnt++) {
        OptionPos memory option = OptionPos(cnt, true);
        posOfOption[options[cnt]] = option;
    }
    votingStarted = true;
}

function vote(uint option) public {
    require(option >= 0 && option < options.length);
    require(!(hasVoted[msg.sender]));
    votes[option] += 1;
    hasVoted[msg.sender] = true;
}

function vote(string memory optionName) public {
    require(!(hasVoted[msg.sender]));
    
    OptionPos memory optionPos = posOfOption[optionName];
    require(optionPos.exists);
    
    votes[optionPos.pos] += 1;
    hasVoted[msg.sender] = true;
}

function getVotes() public view returns (uint[] memory) {
    return votes;
}
```

}

**Facing below error:** { contracts: {}, errors: [ ':1:1: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition.\n' + ' ... { ... \n' + ' ^\n' ], sourceList: [ '' ], sources: {} }

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if your .sol file is encoded in UTF-8 without BOM. You can open your contract file in a text editor such as VS Code or Notepad++ and go to encoding and covert it to UTF-8.

Comment: yes it was encoded without BOM